# sending email from php application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to send email to the users via my application  but i keep get net work error

Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.

```
  if ($send_email == 'on') {

                            //$this->_send_mail($row['mem_real_name'], $m_title, $meeting_id, $row['mem_email']);
                        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
                        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                        $config['smtp_user'] = 'admin';
                        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxx';
                        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';

                        $this->load->library('email');
                        $this->email->initialize($config);

                        $this->email->from('someone@gmail', 'mamoun');
                        $this->email->to('someone@gmail.com'); 
                        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
                $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

                $this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();    


                        }
```

I also tried this code...same error

```
    $from_add = "xyz@kku.edu.sa";
        $to_add = "someonme@kku.edu.sa";
        $subject = "test"; 
        $message = "teest";
        $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
        $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
//$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=Windows-1256" . "\r\n";

        if (mail($to_add, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo 'good';

        } else {

            echo 'nooo';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the port is not working and the 
                        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
instead i put the IP address in numeric form 192.168.0.x 
and the port is 25 instead